# How to access values of dynamic created textbox using gridview rowdatabound

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am stuck with a problem. I need to create a control to display N Number of Rows and N Number of columns
from database. I am able to show data using gridview control. My problem is I want to show textbox in some of the columns.
I have used Gridview's rowdatabound Event to add columns dynamically at run time (working well). The problem I am facing is I am
not able to access the values of dynamic created textboxes. I also know this is because gridview is losing its state on postback.

```
protected void grdVaultStats_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {

            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                TextBox txtVaultStatValue = new TextBox();
                txtVaultStatValue.ID = "txtVaultStatValue";
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txtVaultStatValue);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posted Kindly check.

Comment: Okay so when you are trying to access the value of textbox? Yes you are correct the dynamically control will not even loose its state but the control itself will be removed after postback. Whay you are creating it dynamically? Why not have it in the template and set the _visibility_ of textbox dynamically?

Comment: The number of columns are Not fixed. That's why.

Comment: Okay and when you want to get the data from textbox?

Comment: Why do you want to add `TextBox` in `RowDataBound` event?

Comment: There is a Save button Outside of Gridview. I want data to be saved on the click of Save button.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Then how I will add textboxes? Do you have any alternate?